# jscript Number constructor by locale

Tags: constructor, numbers, jscript

Does anybody know which symbol is used by jscript's Number constructor to separate decimal places? Is it always a dot or dependent on locale?

I´m trying to create a number as follows:
Number(2,11): 
But the result is NaN

I would bet that the symbol is always a dot but I would like someone to confirm that. Is there a way to indicate which symbol should be used for decimal places?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a dot, though there are a number of other legal syntaxes

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3

Comment: Thanks for confirming.